# Clear Button Name Parameter in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi Im new to ASP and MVC3 and my question is how can i clear the button name parameter in my Post because everytime I refreshes my page after clicking the button with the button parameter , the Value of my last clicked button is still there, is there any way to clear this thing up after Submit or when refreshing the page in Controller or by using Jquery?

Thanks

Heres my Code Snippet:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult HistoryPage(HistoryModel model, string btnAction)
    {
        if (Session["HistoryId"] != null)
        {
            switch (btnAction)
            {
                case "Delete History":
                    DeleteHistory(model, ref deleteHistoryError, ref deleteHistorySucesss);
                    break;
                case "AddHistory":
                    AddHistory(model);
                    break;

            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Here is the DeleteHistory

```
private static void DeleteHistory(HistoryModel model, ref string ErrorMessage, ref string SuccessMessage)
        {

                    foreach (var item in model.HistoryIds)
                    {
                        if (item != "")
                        {
                            bool result = Int32.TryParse(item, out HistoryIds);
                            if (result)
                            {
                                var History= db.History.Find(HistoryId);
                                bool HistoryExist = true;

                                if (History.HistoryId != null)
                                {

                                    History.LogicalDelete = true;
                                    History.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
                                    db.SaveChanges();


                                    SuccessMessage = "History  successfully deleted";
                                }
                                else 
                                {
                                    ErrorMessage = "Unable to delete History.";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ErrorMessage))
                    {
                        SuccessMessage = String.Empty;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

my Cshtml Button below my form

```
<input type="submit" name="btnAction" class="btnMultiDelete button_example button_example_small div-bottom-3 w100Percent txtAlignLeft"
                                value="Delete History" id="btnDeleteHistory" />
```

Comment: how you posting data to this controller ?

Comment: @FrebinFrancis Sorry, forgot to include the DeleteHistory Code Snippet

Comment: Show us your cshtml code.

Comment: @ramiramilu added the button in my cshtml

Comment: @FrebinFrancis updated question

Comment: You have to make a `GET` after `POST`, this will prevent you in making the same post on hitting F5 (because browser will cache your last POST request and will make the same when you hit F5). So in your action, use `RedirectToAction` and transfer the call to `GET` action. If you redirect ot GET after POSt, browser will hold the GET request and will make the same when you hit F5, so your post action will not be called.

Comment: @ramiramilu so i will change my `return view(model)` to redirect to action?

Comment: Yes, do it that way `return RedirectToAction("Get Action name")`. And let me know if it works for you or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On browser refresh (clicking on F5), Browser issues the last request which was made (in your case it is `post`). This is the default behavior of the browser.

So we have to follow `PRG` pattern here. PRG - `POST-REDIRECT-GET`. so in your code instead of returning view, you have to `return RedirectToAction("Get Action Name")`. In this case, the last request for the browser would be `GET` and when you do a subsequent refresh, it will issue a `GET` request instead of `POST`.

Your code should be something like this -

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult HistoryPage(HistoryModel model, string btnAction)
    {
        if (Session["HistoryId"] != null)
        {
            switch (btnAction)
            {
                case "Delete History":
                    DeleteHistory(model, ref deleteHistoryError, ref deleteHistorySucesss);
                    break;
                case "AddHistory":
                    AddHistory(model);
                    break;
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Get Action Name ...");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: or is it possible to add `return RedirectToAction("Get Action Name ...");` to the private function for Delete? will it override the `return View(model)`

Comment: No, that is not a good practice, why would want to do redirect in private or business methods? You have to do redirections in Controller actions.

Comment: just saw that I have Condition if DeleteHistory return value is Error or Success, Added `return RedirectionToAction` if success, let me test this

Comment: Yes based on the return value of `DeleteHistory` you can either `return View(model)` or do a redirection `return RedirectToAction("Action name")`.